# List strings have "\n" at the end of them, when individually printed "\n" is gone

Tags: python, python-2.4

I'm reading strings from lines in a text file and then putting them into a list, simple enough. However when I return the List, the strings have a new line character at the end of them. When i try printing a value individually with print list[0] for example the new line character will not be present. How do I make it so the list values don't have newline characters in them to begin with? Why is this happening anyway?

Edit: I didn't think code would matter but even in the following i will have problems:

```
file = open("test.txt", "U")
test = []
for line in file:
    line.rstrip()
    test.append(line)
print test
```

Update: I looked up stripping new line characters and using .rstrip() doesn't work

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I had a similar issue with JQuery and using the .trim() (removes whitespace) function worked. So try the python equivalent maybe it'll help you out too

Comment: Printing an item with a newline in it will write an actual newline. It won't write `\n`.

Comment: File contents include newlines. When you use `.readlines()` on a file object they are not stripped.

Comment: How are you reading the file, what are you doing with the lines? Please do show us your code.

Comment: My answer there applies here too; use `.rstrip()` to remove the newlines individually, or use `.splitlines()` to split the file contents in a way that'll remove the newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
file = open("test.txt", "U")
test = []
for line in file:
   line = line.replace("\r\n","").replace("\n","")
   test.append(line)
   print test
```

Comment: This worked but why is replacing "\n" with blankspace working but not .rstrip()? As far as I know .rstrip() is pretty much Python's version of chomp() from perl

Comment: You can use also rstrip but in this way: line = line.rstrip()